# Стили к сайту применяются не сразу, эффект моргания

Tags: javascript, html, css

столкнулся с проблемой на сайте, при обновлении страницы каждый раз подгружаются стили, background-image, нужно сделать так, чтобы стили отображались сразу, нужно закрыть белым фоном, а после загрузки отобразить сам сайт. Как это можно сделать? Как узнать, загрузился ли весь css?

[image: Во время обновления]
[image: После обновления]

Comment: почитай про прелоадеры

Comment: стили то в хэде прописаны, а не в конце боди?

Comment: Через js - Почитайте [статью](https://learn.javascript.ru/onload-ondomcontentloaded) вам нужно будет использовать `DOMContentLoaded` и  `window.addEventListener("load", handle)`

Comment: Стилями в хэде ставишь оверлей с индикатором загрузки (растянув на весь вьюпорт) ➝ в скрипте в хэде мапишь все стилевые элементы `link` страницы (должны следовать строго после скрипта) в массив промисов ➝ по сеттлу всех этих промисов удаляешь оверлей. Более простой но менее надежный вариант: слушаешь событие `readystatechange` на документе и удаляешь оверлей по комплиту. А через `load` на `window` делать не стоит, т.к. это событие на окне способно возникать неоднократно.